# Generate same set of random numbers

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I gave a small racing game that randomnly generates it's course on start up. The course is too long to manually make and was wondering if there is a way I can generate the same randomn numbers every time? I don't want the course to be different everytime...

Would I have to save a list of randomn numbers in a plist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use good old C-functions.

Set a seed for your RNG: `srand(314)`. Get a random number: `int randomNumber = rand();`.

Not tested.. just form memory. Verify that it works. :)

Comment: Ah ok. Wasn't sure if it would generate the same numbers every single time. Would I call srand again if I want to reset? My game is pretty simple and all runs in a single scene.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is to pre generate your random courses. 
Create an assortment that you bundle with your app. 
Then you could just randomly select from the bundled courses.